# Access Session data in Laravel 9 using Vuejs3 and InertiaJs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am working on my first Laravel project using Vuejs for the frontend.  One of the functions of my app is to allow a Super admin to login as a User(impersonate). When I click the `Impersonate Button`, `impersonate` is added to Session so I can access it in the view.  This works in my other Laravel/Blade projects.

**Pages/Users/Index.vue**

```
...
<Link @click="impersonate(user.id)">Impersonate</Link>
... 
<script>
...
methods: {
    impersonate(id) {
        this.$inertia.post(route("user.impersonate", id));
    },
},
...
</script>
```

[image]

**UserController.php**

```
...
public function impersonate(User $user)
{
    /*if(! is_null(auth()->user()->account_id)) {
        return;
    }*/

    $originalId = auth()->user()->id;
    session()->put('impersonate', $originalId);
    auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);

    return redirect('/users');
}
...
```

Impersonation works and I can successfully login as other Users, but I can't figure out how to access Session data inside Vue so I can show a block with a logout link--with Blade I would simply write:

```
@if(session()->has('impersonate'))
    ...
        <div>
            You are impersonating {{auth()->user()->name}}
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="{{route('leave-impersonation')}}">
                Leave Impersonation
            </a>
        </div>
    ...
@endif
```

How can I write the `if` part in Vue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access that variable in your components, you previously have to share it in [HandleInertiaRequests middleware](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data).

For example, here I'm getting logged user's email in the template:

```html
<template>
  {{ $page.props.auth.user.email }}
</template>
```

If you want to access that prop in the script side you'll have to use [usePage](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data#:%7E:text=shared%20data%20appropriately.-,Accessing%20shared%20data,-Once%20you%27ve%20shared).

Example of getting logged user's email in the script section (example made using `Vue3 composition API`, but you can fit it into your needs):

```html
<script setup>
  import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

  const userEmail = usePage().props.value.auth.user.email
</script>
```